# Rails AJAX and refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I am trying to use javascript/ajax to reorder a table. I have the javascript working

javascript

```
var ajax_header = function(e) {
        alert('order_by')
        var header = $(this).attr('id')
        $.post('/users', {sort_by: header, order_by: order_by});
        if (order_by === "ASC")
            order_by = "DESC"
        else
            order_by = "ASC"
    }
    $('.ajax-header').dblclick(ajax_header)
```

this takes the javascript global to change the order from ASC to DESC and back again and hits the post of the users controllers index action. This causes the @users to be reordered. the issue I have is i dont know how to make the table redraw. I can do this using just rails but I want to learn AJAX with rails better and I am finding the documents not very well written.

users controller

```
def index
if !params[:sort_by].nil? && !params[:order_by].nil?
  @users = User.order("#{params[:sort_by]} #{params[:order_by]}").paginate(page: params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js  {}
  end
else
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

end

The view that is drawn

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<% if signed_in? && !current_user?(@user) %>
    <h1>All users</h1>

    <%= will_paginate %>
    <table id="user_table" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Avitar
            <th id="name"class="ajax-header">Name
            <th id="email" class="ajax-header">Email
            <th id="accepted" class="ajax-header">Accepted
            <th id="admin" class="ajax-header">Admin
            <th>Delete
        </tr>
            <ul class="users">
                <%= render @users%>
            </ul>
    </table>
    <%= will_paginate %>
<% else %>
    Only an admin can view this page.
<% end %>
```

this view above is what is drawn. The <%= render @users%> calls a partial and draws out the rest of the table.

As I have said looking at the logs I am hitting the users controller correctly but I just dont know how to force that render to redraw. I can do this in rails but I would like to practice my js.

Comment: if you want a good answer, could you help us out by clarifying exactly what it is you want to happen?

Comment: I have tried. After clicking the header the javascript is called which hits the users controller causing the users to now be in a different order. I do not know how to now show the new users. In the ruby html it is the render @users that draws the table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found out that using javascript was not the best answer. Instead I replaced the columns headers with link_tos and checked if params[:order_by] was nil if so set to DESC if DESC set to ASC and if ASC set to DESC.